# Worksite-The user gets disabled every day morning automatically every morning

Tags: worksite-sdk

We have a worksite user who gets disabled every morning even if we manually enable him in the wsadmin website. The error in the log file is this:

```
cannot migrate user because the sync_id is already set docusers.sync_id field must be cleared before this user can be migrated, 3767:info [1428] phase 2 of 4: synchronizing ds to worksite groups for connection ‘administration’
```

PS: The user is working as contractor, so she left the company once and came back again.

What could be the reason??

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks will for your reply .But I don't have any code for this question . It s an application from ascertus for document management purpose.

Comment: Ah, I see. You tagged this with `[worksite-sdk]` so I assumed it was a code problem. My first instinct is to refer you elsewhere since SO is for programming and software development-related questions (as well as development tools). But, if this is just a Worksite problem, I'm not sure you'll find much help here, and it might get closed as off-topic. You can try [SuperUser](https://www.superuser.com/), but I can't find any Worksite questions there.

Comment: So then where should I post my issue Will?

Comment: I tried SuperUser but there are no posts for worksite

Comment: I'm not sure, it's hard to Google (because "worksite" is a common term) ;( There are a few WorkSite questions on SuperUser and a few on [ServerFault](https://www.serverfault.com). Do you guys have a support contract? There's supposed to be an iManage Worksite community forum [here](https://worksitesupport.autonomy.com/), but I can't connect to it; it appears to be down. Sorry, I feel your pain, but I don't know what to tell you. I don't know a thing about WorkSite, I just saw your post in the review queue and thought I'd try to point you in a better direction. Best of luck though.

Answer (score 1):

You are using DSSync service to sync users from you AD to worksite.

There can be several causes to why this occurs, but the solution is quite simple:

clear the SYNC_ID for that user in the MHGROUP.DOCUSERS table for that user. (set to NULL) on SQL level. For each worksite database you have.

Best regards,

Daniel